# creating a editing function in django that edit a very simple form

Tags: django

I am unable to design an edit function though I have made putting data into the form and rendering it through an HTML file I have made function to delete also but I have no clue of how to edit.
 this is model

```
    from django.db import models

    class Person(models.Model):
      name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
      email=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
```

this is form

```
    from .models import Person
    from django import forms

    class Formm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
       model=Person
        fields=('name','email')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: Please do the official Django tutorial - this is documented.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/